# How to push a file to internal storage?

Tags: adb, fastboot, motorola-moto-g

I want to do this step to root my phone:
Copy it to the internal storage of your device

So the command is:

```
adb push <local file> <remote location>
```

The "local file" is "boot.img"
What is name for my phone's "internal storage"?

Comment: `/sdcard/` or `/storage/emulated/0/`

Comment: A boot.img is mostly installed via `fastboot`and therefore doe snot have to be pushed via adb to the device. You should edit your question and add more details like the manufacturer and model name of your phone, the Android version your phone runs and the link to the root tutorial you use.

Comment: I'm following this tutorial https://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g7/how-to/moto-g7-twrp-root-t3914112?nocache=1 to root my moto g7 play

Comment: that's correct, don't flash it, just push to /sdcard and patch it with Magisk Manager (step 5 is important) *'adb pull /sdcard/Download/magisk_patched.img'* will pull the patched boot.img back to PC's platform-tools folder

Comment: Thanks I got there, then went into "Recovery Mode" and then get "no command", press power and vol and go to recovery menu. Then reboot and it's still not installed. Will try using TWRP

Answer (score 4):

```
adb push <the file> /sdcard/
```

if `/sdcard` is not available, try

```
adb push <the file> /storage/emulated/0/
```